# Display XAML image in WebBrowser control

Tags: image, xaml, webbrowser-control, windows-phone-7

What I want to achieve is a navigation-like or google-maps-like effect (using new Windows Phone Developer Tools 7.1).

I've got a vector image (a piece of a map) converted to a XAML file. I'd like to display it in the webbrowser control (or any other) in the way that is known from navigations - with the possibility to zoom in and out, and to shift around it.

Can anyone advice me of how to do it? I'll be really, really grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WriteableBitmap to create a bitmap in isolated storage of your map and use an img tag to display it in the browser.